# Worklight Direct Update URL

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm developing a Worklight Hybrid apps targeting iOS and Android, on top of Worklight security feature we have another Web Server doing the Authentication and ACL.

Basically the Direct update feature should be available to any user without the needs to Login, therefore I've added a few White List into the ACL to make sure those user didn't get prompted for Login just for the update.

So far I've whitelisted below URL, it works in my development Machine.

```
apps/services/api/MYAPP/android/setup
apps/services/api/MYAPP/android/update
apps/services/api/MYAPP/iphone/setup
apps/services/api/MYAPP/iphone/update
```

But surprisingly it failed in Production server as the URL to perform direct update was actually as below:

```
apps/services/api/MYAPP/iphone/0/update?action=base64....
```

Why the /0/ was in place and what are the possible value?

Thank in advance.

Comment: What version of Worklight studio you are using?

Answer (score 0):

It is based on your Worklight studio version.

- For Worklight Studio version < 6.2, the direct update URL is `PROTOCOL://<DOMAIN>:<PORT>/<CONTEXT_PATH>/apps/services/api/<APP_NAME>/<ENVIRONMENT>/updates?action=getzip&skin=<SKIN_NAME>&x-wl-app-version=<VERSION>`
- For Worklight Studio version >= 6.2, the direct update URL is `PROTOCOL://<DOMAIN>:<PORT>/<CONTEXT_PATH>/directUpdate/<APP_NAME>/<ENVIRONMENT>/<VERSION>?skin=<skinName>&action= getzip`

Comment: I wasn't getting the >= 6.2 URL which with the "directUpdate" path, i am getting ..iphone/0/update.., the /0/ is the problem I'm facing.

Comment: @PeirHwa.Soo, /0 is always there in the URL